Postgres null safe addition
Other than coalesce(col1, 0) + coalesce(col2, 0) is there any built in shorthand function, like least, that will let me do null safe addition?

For convenience, you can wrap either of the functions proposed below as a custom operator if you do that often.

That's just coalesce(col1+col2, col1, col2, 0).

That’s gonna get very long very fast but yeah that’s it I guess thanks

There is nothing built in, but you can create your own:
CREATE FUNCTION null_safe_sum(VARIADIC numeric[]) RETURNS numeric
LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$$SELECT sum(n) FROM unnest($1) AS u(n)$$;

SELECT null_safe_sum(1, 2, NULL, 7, NULL);

 null_safe_sum 
═══════════════
            10
(1 row)

This uses the fact that sum() ignores NULL values.

Wouldn’t doing this unfolding slow the query down?

Sure, but it simplifies the code. You cannot have both ease of use and speed.
